# this.reactContext always returning null from android native module (react-native)

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

this.reactContext variable within my Android native module is consistently returning a null value.

`UsbThermalPrinter printer = new UsbThermalPrinter(this.reactContext); this is the line that always returns attempts to invoke virtual method java.lang.reflect.method java.lang.class.getMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.class) on a null object reference`

```
public class PrinterHelper extends ReactContextBaseJavaModule {
  Context reactContext;

  private int leftDistance = 0;
  private int lineDistance = 33;
  private int printGray = 10;
  private int startMode = 0;

  PrinterHelper(ReactApplicationContext context) {
    super(context);

    this.reactContext = context;
  }
  
  @Override
  public String getName() {
    return "PrinterHelper";
  }

 

  @ReactMethod
  public void printImage(String path, int height, int width, Callback onErrorOccurred) {
    Bitmap bitmapData = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    bitmapData = PrinterHelper.resizeImage(bitmapData, width, height);
    UsbThermalPrinter printer = new UsbThermalPrinter(this.reactContext);

    try {
      printer.start(startMode);
      printer.setAlgin(UsbThermalPrinter.ALGIN_MIDDLE);
      printer.printLogo(bitmapData, false);
    } catch (PrintException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
      String Result = e.toString();

      Log.d("Error using thermal printer to print: ", Result);

      onErrorOccurred.invoke(Result);
    } finally {
      printer.stop();
    }
  }
```

I tried in different ways to access this.reactContext but still getting the same error which is attempts to invoke virtual method java.lang.reflect.method java.lang.class.getMethod(java.lang.String, java.lang.class) on a null object reference.